# Difference between tab-delimited text file generated by PHP and Excel

Tags: php, excel, file, csv

I'm kind of in a pickle where my client needs to import tab delimited text file to his own system (FIAdmin SCS). Unfortunately the client nor the support team of the software don't know anything about PHP. They keep getting errors that the file is in wrong format.

I'm generating the files from DB like this:

```
    $fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
foreach ($results as $key=>$res) {        
    $put[$key][1] = "DOT"; //Third party administrator
    $put[$key][2] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][3] = 10030; //Dealer number
    $put[$key][4] = trim($res["keyfob_nr"]); //Contract number
    $put[$key][5] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][6] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][7] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][8] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][9] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][10] = trim($res["first_name"]);
    $put[$key][11] = trim($res["last_name"]);
    $put[$key][12] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][13] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][14] = trim($res["address"]);
    $put[$key][15] = trim($res["city"]);
    $put[$key][16] = trim($res["state"]);
    $put[$key][17] = trim($res["zip"]);
    $put[$key][18] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][19] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][20] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][21] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][22] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][23] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][24] = trim($res["vehicle_odometer"]);
    $put[$key][25] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][26] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][27] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][28] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][29] = trim($res["vehicle_year"]);
    $put[$key][30] = trim($res["vehicle_vin"]);
    $put[$key][31] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][32] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][33] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][34] = date("n/d/Y"); //Sale date
    $put[$key][35] = ""; //Empty - vehicle purchase date
    $put[$key][36] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][37] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][38] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][39] = ""; //Empty - auto code (only if no VIN is provided)
    $put[$key][40] = ""; //Lien Holder number
    $put[$key][41] = ""; //Empty - reinsurance ID
    $put[$key][42] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][43] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][44] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][45] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][46] = ""; //Empty - cancel check number
    $put[$key][47] = date("n/d/Y"); //Empty - vehicle in service date (only for new cars)
    $put[$key][48] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][49] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][50] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][51] = ""; //Empty - member id
    $put[$key][52] = ""; //Empty - no charge back flag
    $put[$key][53] = ""; //Empty - contract entry date
    $put[$key][54] = ""; //Empty
    $put[$key][55] = trim("K".substr((string)$res["amount"], 0, 1)); //Plan code. REQUIRED                
    $put[$key][56] = 7; //Rate Book id. REQUIRED
    $put[$key][57] = "N"; //New or used. REQUIRED
    $put[$key][58] = 0; //Deductible amount. REQUIRED
    $put[$key][59] = 0; //Deductible type. REQUIRED
    $put[$key][60] = $res["term"] == 3 ? 36 : 60; //Contract Term Months. REQUIRED
    $put[$key][61] = 999999; //Contract Term Mileage. REQUIRED        
    for ($i = 62; $i < 168; $i++) {
        if ($i == 139) {
            $put[$key][$i] = "SGPY";
        }
        else {
            $put[$key][$i] = " ";
        }
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $put[$key], "\t");
    //fwrite($fp, implode("\t", $put[$key]));
}
fclose($fp);
```

When I import the file to Excel, it's visually exactly the same as the sample file I'm given (sample is a *.xlsx file, which according to them works when exported). I've tried various ways including using spaces instead blank strings, `fwrite()` instead of `fputcsv()`, `\t` instead of `chr(9)`, `\r\n` in the end of `implode()` and so on. None of these seem to work.

The only difference I can see is the file size. My generated files are all 396 bytes, but the original is ~254 bytes. So as I've ran out of ideas... why is PHP generated file larger? What extra info does it add that could ruin my work?

Comment: SUGGESTION: find yourself a text editor that supports "view as hex". My guess is the PHP might be generated on a Linux server ... and might have newline (instead of Windows CR/LF) ... which might confuse the heck out of Excel.

Comment: @palsm4, What am I looking here exactly? The [original file](https://postimg.org/image/5598ksa8x/) seems a lot shorter indeed than the [generated file](https://postimg.org/image/bufs0svkx/). It seems the right/working "tabs" are marked as 0x0909, but PHP generates it as 0x0920. But then again, in the beginning of the file, PHP generates the tabs correctly?!

Comment: @paulsm4 you were right. After checking the hexadecimal code I think I resolved the issue. Line endings and tabs were not generated properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[From the manual on `fputcsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv)

> **Note:** If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the [auto_detect_line_endings](http://php.net/filesystem.configuration#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

Depending on what system you're running PHP to generate these csv files, and depending on the input file itself, and this configuration option in PHP, you could get some varying results.

It should be noted that `xlsx` files aren't comma-separated or tab-separated files. You may certainly be able to import CSV files into Excel, but it is ultimately up to Excel how to interpret that import. This may be an issue with the person doing the importing in Excel and may have nothing to do with PHP. It may also be a configuration issue with the server running PHP that's generating the files that's muddying the whole process. It remains unclear exactly where the culprit is or how to fix it without more accurate information as to steps that reproduce the problem.